# How to detect WLAN?

Tags: java, wifi

How to write a Java program that can detect WLAN? Because I have no idea how to start and where to search for even from google. Maybe anyone can give me some idea like what API or the step then i will definately try out myself first. I am new to network topic so no idea where to search from.

Comment: The solution, as Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen noted, requires calling external code and is thus platform specific.  What platform(s) are you targetting?

Comment: Something work like kismet, windows 7

Comment: kismet uses native, platform-specific code and it's not written in Java, so how is it relevant to your query?

Comment: Just want to know how to use java to write a program that can detect wlan

Comment: Would you like to write a program that shows WLAN access points or a program that shows if you are connected to a WLAN?

Comment: Want to write a program that shows WLAN access points

Answer (score 1):

There is no facilities present in the Java Runtime Library to identify WLAN, so you cannot do it without invoking external code in order to do whatever you need to do. This can either be commands or DLL's.  The exact procedure varies.